# testing buildRules cakephp

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I've been trying cakephp 3 since yesterday. And I'm interested to use the unit testing.

I have succeed test my add action. But, I have difficulties on tracking if there are some validation errors. How could I make a test for testDefaultValidation() and buildRules(), since their content only `$this->markTestIncomplete('Not implemented yet.'); ??`

Thank you.

Comment: In case, suppose if u have supplied validation for not empty , then when you test for adding then empty value shouldn't be saved and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a unit test using the method `checkRules` which is available on your table, see http://api.cakephp.org/3.3/source-class-Cake.Datasource.RulesAwareTrait.html#40-80.

As an example if you had a `comments` table that required an `id` from `articles` to exist the following would test you had setup `buildRules` correctly.

```
$table = TableRegistry::get('Comments');

// Where an row in the articles table with id 123 doesn't exist
$comment = $table->newEntity([
    'article_id' => 123
]);

$result = $table->checkRules($comment);
$this->assertFalse($result);

$expected = [
    'article_id' => [
        '_existsIn' => 'This value does not exist'
    ]
];
$this->assertEquals($expected, $comment->errors());
```

Comment: Thank you. You rock! Btw, here is the proper location for the code? `PatientsTableTest.php` or `PatientsControllerTest.php`? Or it is just the same, since I can place and run it just fine either in `PatientsTableTest` or in `PatientsController`

Comment: No problem! You could stick it in either although I would put it in `PatientsTableTest` as you're testing a table method.